# Prevent text from breaking on a new line around the <sub></sub> tags using html2pdf

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, html2pdf

I am using spipu/html2pdf PDF creation library in order to render some text on an A4 page.

The text is wrapped in

tag and goes something like this:

```
 <p>Chemical corrosion is one of the ways to break down a substrate. 
C<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> is one of the strongest suited for this 
 purpose.
```

Somtimes the part with `C<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>` will be a the end of the line in which case it will break on a new line along the  tags and this is something that I would like to prevent.

I have tried wrapping it in an element on it's own and setting white-space: nowrap; on it but it does not seem to have any effect.

The library has partial support for up to css 2.1.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly is it you want the output to be?

Comment: The entire `C<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>` formula should one one line instead of breaking on multiple lines.